# read content from request.files _ nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I need to read the content of **txt** file or **CSV** file that user uploads from form-data.

so I know I can save the file in an upload directory and then read it from storage. but I need to know is there any way I can read from request, without saving it in local storage?
I also I checked my file has some property like this:

```
{
  name: 'emals.txt',
  data: <Buffer 27 61 6c 69 40 67 2e 63 6f 6d 27>,
  size: 11,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  md5: '09c3de70dcf2d0f0ec6fcb79ed147c4a',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

as we see we have data its Buffer . is there any way I could use this buffer on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the buffer into a node.js string using

```
buffer.toString(encoding);
```

Use encoding parameter `ascii` to get the string from a 7-bit encoded file.
In your case, the buffer is stored in the `data` property of the object.